# C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource.getConnection method bring null after deployment

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, datasource, c3p0

Here is my code for c3p0 configuration... 
when app server is being started, i am initializing the datasources that came from dbDef(db definitions table)

```
SessionFactory sessionFactoryByServer;
Connection jdbcConnectionC3P0;
List<Map<String, Object>> connectionSourceList; // object combopooleddatasource 
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List <DBDef> dbDefs = new ArrayList<DBDef>();
    try {
        dbDefs = getAllServerIpAddresses();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connectionSourceList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dbDefs.size(); i++) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> cpdsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            cpds.setDebugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces(false);
            cpds.setDriverClass(dbDefs.get(i).getDriver());
            cpds.setJdbcUrl(dbDefs.get(i).getConnectionURL());
            cpds.setUser(dbDefs.get(i).getUserName());
            cpds.setPassword(dbDefs.get(i).getPassword());
            cpds.setDataSourceName(dbDefs.get(i).getIpAddress());
            cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5); 
            cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(1800);
            cpds.setMinPoolSize(10); 
            cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(1);
            cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
            cpds.setMaxPoolSize(50);
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure(dbDefs.get(i).getHbmCfgXmlPath());
            cfg.setProperty("connection.provider_class", dbDefs.get(i).getConnectionProvideClass())
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", dbDefs.get(i).getAcquireIncrement())
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", dbDefs.get(i).getMaxSize())
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", dbDefs.get(i).getMinSize())
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", dbDefs.get(i).getTimeout())
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", dbDefs.get(i).getMaxStatements()) 
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", dbDefs.get(i).getIdleTestPeriod())
                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");     
            ServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.buildServiceRegistry());
            cpdsMap.put("serverIp", dbDefs.get(i).getIpAddress());
            cpdsMap.put("dataSource", cpds);
            cpdsMap.put("sessionFactory", sessionFactory);              
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

after initialize c3p0 datasources to `List<Map<String, Object>> connectionSourceList;`, when i want to gether some data from 3 databases sequentially, in this list the third one forget some of its attributes i think. here is the problem where occured.

```
    private SessionFactory retCurSessionFactory(String ipAddress) throws SQLException {
    SessionFactory currentSessionFactory = null;
    for (Map<String, Object> cpdsMap : connectionSourceList) {
            sessionFactoryByServer = (SessionFactory)cpdsMap.get("sessionFactory");
            jdbcConnectionC3P0 = ((ComboPooledDataSource)cpdsMap.get("dataSource")).getConnection();//getConnection brings null here, but only in app server not in my local machine.
            currentSessionFactory = (SessionFactory)cpdsMap.get("sessionFactory");
        }
    }
    return currentSessionFactory;
}
```

getConnection method brings null when program calls this method when running on app server. Tomcat is same as at development envirement.(copy-pasted) 
the internet connection between my place and app server sometimes cut off for miliseconds and before i found this getConnection is null i get this stacktrace below...

2016-03-28 19:00:21 INFO  AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:2016-03-28 19:00:22 WARN  BasicResourcePool:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xxx.xx.x", user "username
", database "xxxx", SSL off

AND

java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!

EDIT: The hba configuration content is added.

```
local   all  all                trust
host    all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
host    all  all  ::1/128       trust
host raritan +odbc 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+no+pg_hba.conf+entry+for+host

Comment: thanks for reply. but i have already looked these answers you pointed. as my customer mentioned about the postgre servers are being setup by an image file. so why i have no problem while fetching data from other connections. their setup are the same.

Comment: The error message "*no pg_hba.conf entry*" is pretty clear. Your Postgres (**not** "*postgre*" btw) configuration doesn't allow a connection from your application server. [edit] your question and show us the **complete** contents of the `pg_hga.conf` otherwise this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I got it SOME content from our client. I can show it tomarrow. Thanks for reply.

Comment: local   all  all                trust
host    all  all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
host    all  all  ::1/128       trust
host raritan +odbc 0.0.0.0/0 md5

this is the hba configuration that our client provided to me. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mistake while initiating ComboPooledDataSource object from dbDef object. I created a new row on database where I get connection properties. There must be a space char in the definition at DB row. So this code works fine for me to initiate db connections dynamically.